# QC/ALM OTA- IgnoreHtmlFormat is not working as expected in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ota, hp-quality-center, vba

I have written a code in Excel VBA for updating the descriptin of test case in test lab. In that code,Once I have connected to the project, I am setting 
tdConnection.IgnoreHtmlFormat = True and later I am updating the description.
Now the problem I am facing is that When IgnoreHtmlFormat = True then after updating I am seeing html tags in description and When I am setting IgnoreHtmlFormat = False then I am not getting any html tags in updated description. but I think,right behaviour should be opposite of it. can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are updating the description.
If the description was created with **IgnoreHtmlFormat = False** then the description will contain html tags no matter the value of IgnoreHtmlFormat you are using to retrieve the info.

My guess is that you are retrieving the descriptio, which contains HTML tags, and update it, but this time, with **IgnoreHtmlFormat = True**.

Even if no HTML tags will be created in your update, the tags are already present in your updated description, and they are treated like regular text.